# asp.net core API conditional URL rewrite to different domains

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, url-rewriting, startup, asp.net-core-middleware

We are trying to dstribue the one application api requests to different application apis. 
For example:

1. [POST] https://{domain1}/api/authentication to [POST] https://{domain2}/api/authentication
2. https://{domain1}/api/Persons to https://{domain3}/api/Persons (depends on header values)

Is there a way this can be implemented at global level like middleware or something like this?

I have tried the below option, but not working. It seems URL rewriting working only for the same domain.

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()  
              AddRewrite(@"api/values", "https://av21.azurewebsites.net/api/home", true);  
 app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Comment: According to asp.net core url rewrite only support inbound url rewrite, it doesn't support Outbound Rules.  If you will host your application on IIS, I suggest you could try to use IIS url rewrite to achieve your requirement.If you want to use middleware to solve achieve your requirement, you should write the custom middleware and check the request path and header, then send the request to the right domain and generate the response according to the remote api result.

Comment: Thank you @BrandoZhang.  App hosted on Azure Linux app service, not I can change app server settings. Using middleware means it's more of calling another API and get the response and bypass all remaining middlewares and send the response back to client.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you could check the request domain in the middleware, and check if you call another api you could directly return the response without call next middleware. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Great, thanks again @BrandoZhang. Will try that.